# Why is this Queue.hasNext() implementation checking the current node and not the next node?

Tags: java, data-structures

I was reading the source code for a Queue class and came across this, which I didn't fully understand:

```
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    private Node current = first;  // node containing current item

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Item next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Item item = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return item;
    }
}
```

In the `hasNext()` method implementation, it checks if the current node is null; shouldn't it be checking for`current.next != null`?

The `current` field can have a value, but it can also be the last node and the next node is actually null. So I don't understand why checking the current node is correct.

Comment: In `next()`, before the value is returned, `current` is reassigned - `current = current.next;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current` holds the node for the *next* item to be returned, not the item that was most recently returned. So there is no next item if and only if `current` is null.

You can see this because `current` is initialised to `first` before the first item is actually returned, and because when `next()` is called, `current` is stepped forwards by one but the item from the *old* node is returned, not the new one.

It is this way because if `current` held the previously-returned node, there would be no sensible value for `current` to have on the first iteration, before any item has been returned by `next()`.